# How to call and API endpoint on initialize. Value is still null

Tags: flutter, api, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

I am trying to get user information from an API. For this, I created a user object. I want to call the function and store it in a user. But the problem is, that I cannot use await and wait till all the data is there.

So instead of async and await, I tried to use .then and fill userInfo with the data. But now the email value is not showing. It is showing 'loading...'.

If I use Future I cannot do user.email.

**Is it better to use FutureBuilder? Or try and use Async and Await (the call takes 2.5 seconds)**

### Here is the code

```dart
class Addressbook extends StatefulWidget {
  const Addressbook({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Addressbook> createState() => _AddressbookState();
}

class _AddressbookState extends State<Addressbook> {
  User? userInfo;
  Future<User> getUserInformation() async {
    User user = await UserService().getUserById(12345);
    return user;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    getUserInformation().then((response) {
      userInfo = response;
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Mijn adresboek'),
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0.5,
        titleTextStyle: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 21,
          color: Colors.black,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
      ),
      body: Text(userInfo?.email ?? "loading..."),

    );
  }
}
```

## What do I want to archive?

I want to display user data on the screen. In this case I want to show the email.

## What is the problem?

User is not filled with data on init (probably because it is still loading to get the data).

## My question

How can I solve this problem? Is async await a solution or should I use FutureBuilder? Can you give me a working sample?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use futurebuilder or you can use in  initstate to fetch api

[image]

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10), () {
      setState(() {
        userinfo = "response";
      });
      // userinfo = "response";

    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

Inside the widget

```
Text(userinfo != null ? userinfo.toString() : "loading..."),
```

**SAmple Code**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
//import 'package:pucon/home.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String? userinfo = null;
  String? userinfo2 = null;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10), () {
      setState(() {
        userinfo = "response";
      });
      // userinfo = "response";
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: [
          Text(""),
          Text(""),
          Text(userinfo != null ? userinfo.toString() : "loading..."),
          Row(
            children: [
              FutureBuilder(
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                    return Container(
                        child: Text(userinfo2.toString()), );
                  } else {
                    return SizedBox(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      height: 45,
                      width: 45,
                    );
                    // else
                    //   return Container(
                    //     child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    //     height: 45,
                    //     width: 45,
                    //   );
                  }
                },
                future: _future(),
              ),
            ],
          )
          // InsertData(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _future() async {
   await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
     userinfo2 = "Completed";
      // setState(() {
      //
      // });
      // userinfo = "response";
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lava! It is working. I indeed just needed to do setState... I forgot that. I have another question and want to know your opinion :D. Is it better to pass the user object to the next screen? Or should I pass the ID and call the API endpoint again?

Comment: if the data was like stock market price or high volatile  or changing value then consider api call else pass argument and  reduce loading the server

Comment: Aha okay, that makes sense. Hey, I got another question about SOLID principles (if you don't mind ;p). Let's say I have 2 types of addresses. A billing address and a shipping address. I need to be able to change data such as the city or postcode. 

Is it better to make 2 separate screens? The fields are identical except for 1 field.  The shipping address does not have an email field in it.

Or is it better to make 1 screen and constantly check if we are dealing with a billing address or a shipping address?

Do you get what I mean :D? What do you think is better?